# How to set Formik initialValues using interpolated strings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am trying to use Formik initialValues with an id provenient from props. The way one would do it is like this:

```
<Formik
     initialValues={{
       smallPrice: smallPrice,
       bigPrice: bigPrice,
     }}
```

I am trying, however, to create the names for initial values like this, but it won't work:

```
<Formik
     initialValues={{
       `smallPrice${props.id}`: `smallPrice${props.id}`,
       `bigPrice${props.id}`: `bigPrice${props.id}`,
     }}
```

What alternative can be used?

Comment: I think you have an array of inputs, that is why you are doing this way, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need `[]` to create dynamic keys

```js
{
   [`smallPrice${props.id}`]: `smallPrice${props.id}`,
   [`bigPrice${props.id}`]: `bigPrice${props.id}`,
 }
```